# How to combine multiple chains from rjags into one chain in R?

Tags: r, jags

I typically call JAGS from rjags with several chains for diagnostic purposes (e.g., 4 chains).
After that I often want to do some post processing on the posterior parameter estimates (e.g., use predicted values, compute additional statistics). However, at this point it is a nuisance having the chains stored in a list.

What's a good way to combine the chains into a single parameter list?

Comment: you can combine the chains with `rbind` : `mcmcmtot <- rbind(mcmc[[1]], mcmc[[2]], mcmc[[3]])`and after work with this new object. For example : `pairs(mcmctot)`.

Answer (score 6):

The `runjags` package has the function [`combine.mcmc`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/runjags/docs/combine.mcmc). Its default setting is to combine one or more chains and return a single chain. E.g.,

```
library(runjags)
fit <- combine.mcmc(multichainfit)
```

It also has other options for combining chains.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the `rjags` and `coda` solution. Say you generate two chains like this:

```
library(rjags)
x <- rnorm(100)
model.str <- 'model {for (i in 1:100) {
  x[i] ~ dnorm(mu, sd)}
  mu ~ dnorm(0, .0001)
  sd ~ dgamma(0.1, 0.1)}'
jags <- jags.model(textConnection(model.str), data = list(x = x),n.chains=2)
smpls <- coda.samples(model=jags,n.iter=2,variable.names=c("mu","sd"))
smpls
# [[1]]
# Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) output:
# Start = 1 
# End = 2 
# Thinning interval = 1 
#               mu        sd
# [1,] -0.09152588 0.9009973
# [2,]  0.05586651 1.0482184
# 
# [[2]]
# Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) output:
# Start = 1 
# End = 2 
# Thinning interval = 1 
#              mu        sd
# [1,] 0.06893182 0.7317955
# [2,] 0.13599206 0.8517304
# 
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "mcmc.list"
```

You can combine the two (or arbitrarily many) chains into a matrix by

```
do.call(rbind, smpls)
#               mu        sd
# [1,] -0.09152588 0.9009973
# [2,]  0.05586651 1.0482184
# [3,]  0.06893182 0.7317955
# [4,]  0.13599206 0.8517304
```

If you want an object of class `mcmc`, simply use the function `mcmc`:

```
mcmc(do.call(rbind, smpls))

# [[1]]
# Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) output:
# Start = 1 
# End = 4 
# Thinning interval = 1 
#               mu        sd
# [1,] -0.09152588 0.9009973
# [2,]  0.05586651 1.0482184
# [3,]  0.06893182 0.7317955
# [4,]  0.13599206 0.8517304
```

If you want, you can preserve the `start`, `end`, or `thin` attribute of the original chain. For example to preserve `thin`:

```
mcmc(do.call(rbind, smpls), thin=thin(smpls))
```

(Of course you cannot preserve all three attributes)